# CSS3: Chevron-side banner has aliased edges

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a chevron-side banner in CSS3 (not sure what the object is really called), but I am getting alias issues in Chrome. I tried using the `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` attribute, however I am still getting alias issues in Chrome.

Here is my CSS:

```
.banner {
    height: 0px;
    width: 280px;
    border-left: 20px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 20px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 40px solid black;
    border-top: 40px solid black;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0;
    color: white;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
    Hello World
</div>
```

I've created a fiddle for the issue here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4PWP5/2/

Any help resolving this is appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe there is a fix for this. That is how the browser calculates and renders such large borders. Same thing happens in firefox.

Comment: Would the only alternate be to use .png's then?

Comment: Try applying a tiny 2d transform or maybe even a full rotation.  `transform: rotate(360deg);`

Comment: You might try using border-image along with an SVG image. That should make it possible to have the border scale nicely with the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning**: Here be dragons.
Ahem, I mean SVG.

You should be able to mix, match and cut this sample up to suit your specific needs.

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Zb8/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M 0,0 L 10,0 9.5,5 10,10 0,10 0.5,5 z" fill="black"></path>
    </svg>
    <span>Hello World!</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
}

#container > svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container > span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```